# Launching my GoogleGlass app without using Launchy

Tags: java, android, google-glass

Is it possible to install and launch a native Google Glass App with the Preview GDK without having to use launchy?

I'm having a hard time finding a tutorial/reference on how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I'd start with one of the GDK Sneak Peek sample projects and make sure you can install one of those and launch it. You can even change the voice command from "start to stopwatch" to "release the hounds" or something and check that that works. The way glassware launches is different from conventional Android apps, so your manifest file will need to be different.

Here's the official documentation: 
https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/input/voice#starting_glassware

Comment: Seems like it used to work. Try https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/starting-glassware